# Use Auto generation in coupons doesn't save, weird issue

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

I am testing the Use Auto generation  in the shopping cart promotion but when I tick the box and save the extra manage coupons is added but I can not do anything there. When I check the first tab again the use auto generation is not ticked anymore.

weird!

Anybody has any idea? Do not get any error.

Comment: goto manage coupen code and enter qty etc fill all those details then generate

Comment: Not possible because everything is greyed out

Answer (score 1):

If the option is greyed out in the promotions menu, it needs to be set up first in:

SYSTEM > Configuration > Customers > Promotions

Select Auto Generated Specific Coupon Codes

Make thedesired changes and Save.

Now back in promotions, add your rules and select Specific Coupon Code - Auto Generate option will now appear, Select, and the manage coupon codes options will no longer be greyed out.